Being asked whether it is preferable to use Jacobi's method or an unfamiliar matrix. At a loss as to how to answer.
I found in my notes the exercise below. We are asked whether it is preferable to use Jacobi's method or an iterative method whose matrix and vector I know not where they come from, nor even how they are related to the problem. I was hoping someone could illuminate me as to what we are expected to answer; all I can say is that Jacobi's method converges in this instance (see my work at the bottom).

We want to use an iterative method to solve the linear system:
$$
\begin{aligned}
-2x + y + z/2 &= 4 \\
x - 2y - z/2 &= -4 \\
y + 2z &= 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
We propose calculating the solution to the system using the iterative method:
$$
x_{k+1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 1/4 \\
0 & 1/4 & -1/8 \\
0 & -1/8 & 1/16
\end{pmatrix}
x_k +
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
-1/2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is it better to use this iterative method or the Jacobi method to solve this system?


Now, the system can be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1/2 \\
1 & -2 & -1/2 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
4 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
where the matrix $A$ can be expressed as:
$$
A = D(L + I + U),
$$
for
$$
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
U =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1/2 & -1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
L =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The iterative process for the Jacobi method is:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
x^{(k+1)} = - (L + U)x^{(k)} + D^{-1}b & =
\begin{pmatrix}
 & 2/2 & 1/4 \\
1/2 &  & -1/4 \\
 & -1/2 & 
\end{pmatrix}
x^{(k)} +
\begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 &  &  \\
 & -1/2 &  \\
 &  & 1/2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
-4 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}
 & 2/2 & 1/4 \\
1/2 &  & -1/4 \\
 & -1/2 & 
\end{pmatrix}
x^{(k)} +
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{alignat*}
Jacobi's method converges as
$$
\|B\|_1 = \max_j \sum_i |b_{ij}| = \frac{3}{4} < 1.
$$
